# Store DISPLAY results in a PIC X(n)

Tags: cobol, netcobol

The picture clause defines the format which the DISPLAY command would output to the console. 
Is there a means to "output" the formatted string to a variable? Something like the following, but something that works. The following is an arbitrary example of a number, transformed by a picture, and stored in a string in the currency format.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
 PROGRAM-ID.    Demo1234. 
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
 DATA DIVISION. 
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
 01  Price           Pic     $$$,$$9.99.
 01  Formated-Output Pic     X(10).

 PROCEDURE DIVISION. 

     Move 10.50 to Price.
     Display Price Upon Formated-Output.
     *> Formated-Output would now contain "$10.50    "
     GOBACK.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to `WORKING-STORAGE`.

```
   01  Start-pos       Pic     9(4)    Binary.
```

Replace the `Display Price` statement with

```
       Move 1 to Start-pos
       Inspect Price tallying
           Start-pos for leading spaces
       Move Price (Start-pos:) to Formated-Output
```

The result, `"$10.50"`, followed by 4 spaces is in `Formated-Output`.